# Why did jackson ignore nullable field?

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson

I got following data class

```
data class Statement(val transactions: List<BonusTransactionDto>, val nextQuery: Query? = null)
```

and object mapper

```
@Bean 
fun objectMapper() = jacksonObjectMapper()
```

where `jacksonObjectMapper` is method from `jackson-module-kotlin:2.13.2`

for some reasons after serialization I got json without `nextQuery` field like this

```
{ "transactions": [...] }
```

Why did jackson ignore the field?

Comment: thought that omitting `null`-values is the default... but after testing it again, that doesn't seem the case... seems as if you are using Spring? maybe you want to check your 
(or the default) configuration there, e.g. look for property-inclusion ... or maybe there is another (`@Primary`?) mapper that has `setSerializationInclusion` set to ~non_null?

Comment: Thanks, the problem was in dependency that i used to generate docs snippets, for some reasons someone add `setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)`